# how to group_by day in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

Hello I'm trying to make grouping news by date. I can't understand what is the problem?

feed_entries_controller.rb

```
def index 
  @feed_entries = FeedEntry.page(params[:page]).per_page(12).where('published_at < ?', DateTime.now) 
  @feed_entries_by_day = @feed_entries.group_by { |t| t.published_at.beginning_of_day }
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @feed_entries_by_day.each do |day, feed_entries| %>
  <h3><%= h day.strftime("%d %B %Y") %></h3>
  <%= render @feed_entries%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try with to_date: `@feed_entries_by_day = @feed_entries.group_by{ |t| t.published_at.to_date }`

Comment: @MrYoshiji doesn't work

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: @MrYoshiji displays only the last two dates and group is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data, I suspect our problem is the `published_at` column also contains `time` and we're just interested in the `date` part for the purposes of querying and grouping, and we need to reference the grouped data in the view..

If that's the case, we can amend our `.where()` clause like so:

*feed_entries_controller.rb*

```
def index
  feed_entries = FeedEntry
    .page(params[:page])
    .per_page(12)
    .where('published_at::date <= ?', Date.current)

  @feed_entries_by_day = feed_entries.group_by { |t| t.published_at.to_date }
end
```

And in our view, we need to pick a different name to iterate through our grouped `feed_entries` (I've chosen `entry`)

*index.html.erb*

```
<% @feed_entries_by_day.each do |day, entry| %>
  <h3><%= h day.strftime("%d %B %Y") %></h3>
  <%= render entry%>
<% end %>
```